# jQuery input not hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm working on a new website based on CodeIgniter. I'm trying to hide some elements to my form depending on an input value, but the field doesn't hide but stays disabled.

Here's the code I have :

HTML :

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="form-timezone" class="form-label">Filters<small>Options</small></label>
    <div class="form-input">
        <?php 
            echo form_dropdown('filter', $filters,'', 'id="form-timezone"');
            echo form_dropdown('city', $cities, '', 'id="city"');
            echo form_dropdown('country', $countries, '', 'id="country"');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which basically gives something like :

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="form-input">
        <select name="filter" id="form-timezone">
            <option value="city">City</option>
            <option value="country">Country</option>
        </select>
        <select name="cities" id="city">
            <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
            <option value="London">London</option>
        </select>
        <select name="countries" id="country">
            <option value="fr">France</option>
            <option value="en">England</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(function() {

    $("#city").hide();
    $("#country").hide();

    $("#form-timezone").change(function() {
        if ( $("#form-timezone").val() == "city"){
            $("#city").show();
            $("#country").hide();
        }
        else if ( $("#form-timezone").val() == "country"){
            $("#city").hide();
            $("#country").show();
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to add an `<input>` field to my html, and to hide it in the js, and it worked well. I don't know why, but it seems that only the `form_dropdown` doesn't hide...

Do someone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try replacing $(function() by $(document).ready(function(){ ??

Comment: Yes, the result is the same. But I read that `$(function()` was just a replacement for `$(document).ready(function()` no ?

Comment: Yes, it is shorthand for the same thing.

Comment: Can you show the generated html from your php templating syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by not working.  But your code can be a lot simpler with no if statements.

```
$("#form-timezone").change(function() {
     var el =  $('#' + $(this).val()); // <-- store matched element
     el.show();  // <-- show matched element
    $("#country,#city").not(el).hide(); // <-- hide unmatched element
});
```

And they work fine in this fiddle (they hide and not disable) - tested in Firefox/Chrome/IE9

http://jsfiddle.net/5LNWr/1/

Comment: My code seems to work also on jsfiddle. But on my website, the dropdown lists don't hide. Nevertheless, the input fields are correctly hiding.

Comment: Could it be a sort of "side-effect" from another js file which is included ?

Comment: FOUND IT ! In fact, in the source code, my ids were fine, but when I inspected the elements, it added me some "uniform-" before the dropdown list's id. That's why they were not hiding... Weird !

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La68q/).

The Javascript code you posted was missing a closing `});` after the DOM ready handler.  I've assumed the output is a `<select>` element for each PHP `echo` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the form field "stays disabled." Does this mean they're disabled to begin with? Disabled form elements don't capture events in all browsers (Firefox).

If that isn't the case, can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes they're disabled at the beginning. If I select "City", then the dropdown list City will be enabled.

Comment: I mean, I do nothing to disable them, I just "try" to hide them... But it seems it disables them instead.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or url with an example?

If not, you may want to check if multiple events are bound to the element. Is it possible you have some other plugin running on those elements that might disable them?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="form-input">
        <select name="filter" id="form-timezone">
            <option value="city">City</option>
            <option value="country">Country</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Here a select foreach city and country -->
    </div>
</div>
```

See how there is no id's for City and Country? You cannot select on ID's here.

```
$("#city").show();
$("#country").hide();
```

Won't work. Maybe try

```
var $firstOption= $(“#form-timezone option:first”)
```

Comment: The City and Country you mention are the options of the select. My selects for City and Country have an id. I've updated the sourcecode on my post.